# People Picker in Sharepoint Central Admin 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, error, central-administration, people-picker

My People picker is not working in Central Admin. It is stuck in searching.

But in adding people in Farm Administrator its working fine. I don't know if it has different connection.

This one not working (assigning people in BCS or other service apps):

[image]

This one is working(Assigning people in Farm Admin):

[image]

**In Web Application all is working fine. My problem is in Central Admin.**

Here are the logs:

```
05/19/2021 12:07:25.91  w3wp.exe (0x3880)                           0x4B04  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (POST:http://vgr1:5834/_layouts/15/Picker.aspx?MultiSelect=True&CustomProperty=User%2CSecGroup%3B%3B15%3B%3B%3BFalse&DialogTitle=Select%20People%20and%20Groups&DialogImage=%2F_layouts%2F15%2Fimages%2Fppeople.gif&PickerDialogType=Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeoplePickerDialog%2C%20Microsoft.SharePoint%2C%20Version%3D15.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D71e9bce111e9429c&ForceClaims=False&DisableClaims=False&EnabledClaimProviders=&EntitySeparator=%3B%EF%BC%9B??????&DefaultSearch=&IsDlg=1%20HTTP/1.1)). Parent No    
05/19/2021 12:07:25.91  w3wp.exe (0x3880)                           0x4B04  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (POST:http://vgr1:5834/_layouts/15/Picker.aspx?MultiSelect=True&CustomProperty=User%2CSecGroup%3B%3B15%3B%3B%3BFalse&DialogTitle=Select%20People%20and%20Groups&DialogImage=%2F_layouts%2F15%2Fimages%2Fppeople.gif&PickerDialogType=Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeoplePickerDialog%2C%20Microsoft.SharePoint%2C%20Version%3D15.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D71e9bce111e9429c&ForceClaims=False&DisableClaims=False&EnabledClaimProviders=&EntitySeparator=%3B%EF%BC%9B??????&DefaultSearch=&IsDlg=1%20HTTP/1.1)    b64fc99f-a77d-606a-5b6e-9277e66637ec
05/19/2021 12:07:25.91  w3wp.exe (0x3880)                           0x4B04  SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium      Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=, ClaimsCount=0   b64fc99f-a77d-606a-5b6e-9277e66637ec
05/19/2021 12:07:25.91  w3wp.exe (0x3880)                           0x4B04  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium      Application error when access /_layouts/15/Picker.aspx, Error=A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$PlaceHolderDialogBodySection$ctl05$OriginalEntities="<Entities />").   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)     at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)     at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.GetParametersFromHttpRequest(SPSite site, Boolean bAuthenticated)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, SPAppPrinc... b64fc99f-a77d-606a-5b6e-9277e66637ec
05/19/2021 12:07:25.91* w3wp.exe (0x3880)                           0x4B04  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium      ...ipalToken appPrincipalToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitializeSPRequest()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.EnsureSPRequest()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Request()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.EnsureSPWebRequest(SPWeb web)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext context)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.BaseApplication.Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PreRequestExecuteAppHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web...  b64fc99f-a77d-606a-5b6e-9277e66637ec
05/19/2021 12:07:25.91* w3wp.exe (0x3880)                           0x4B04  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium      ....HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)   b64fc99f-a77d-606a-5b6e-9277e66637ec
05/19/2021 12:07:25.91  w3wp.exe (0x3880)                           0x4B04  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$PlaceHolderDialogBodySection$ctl05$OriginalEntities="<Entities />").    at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)     at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)     at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.GetParametersFromHttpRequest(SPSite site, Boolean bAuthenticated)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, SPAppPrincipalToken appPrinc... b64fc99f-a77d-606a-5b6e-9277e66637ec
05/19/2021 12:07:25.91* w3wp.exe (0x3880)                           0x4B04  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...ipalToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitializeSPRequest()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.EnsureSPRequest()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Request()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.EnsureSPWebRequest(SPWeb web)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext context)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.BaseApplication.Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PreRequestExecuteAppHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.E...  b64fc99f-a77d-606a-5b6e-9277e66637ec
05/19/2021 12:07:25.91* w3wp.exe (0x3880)                           0x4B04  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...xecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) b64fc99f-a77d-606a-5b6e-9277e66637ec
05/19/2021 12:07:25.91  w3wp.exe (0x3880)                           0x4B04  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$PlaceHolderDialogBodySection$ctl05$OriginalEntities="<Entities />").     at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)     at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)     at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.GetParametersFromHttpRequest(SPSite site, Boolean bAuthenticated)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToConte... b64fc99f-a77d-606a-5b6e-9277e66637ec
05/19/2021 12:07:25.91* w3wp.exe (0x3880)                           0x4B04  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        ...xt, Byte[] UserToken, SPAppPrincipalToken appPrincipalToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitializeSPRequest()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.EnsureSPRequest()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Request()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.EnsureSPWebRequest(SPWeb web)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext context)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.BaseApplication.Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PreRequestExecuteAppHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecution...  b64fc99f-a77d-606a-5b6e-9277e66637ec
05/19/2021 12:07:25.91* w3wp.exe (0x3880)                           0x4B04  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        ...Step.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)   b64fc99f-a77d-606a-5b6e-9277e66637ec
05/19/2021 12:07:25.94  w3wp.exe (0x3880)                           0x4B04  SharePoint Foundation           General                         aat87   Monitorable     b64fc99f-a77d-606a-5b6e-9277e66637ec
05/19/2021 12:07:25.94  w3wp.exe (0x3880)                           0x4B04  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://vgr1:5834/_layouts/15/Picker.aspx?MultiSelect=True&CustomProperty=User%2CSecGroup%3B%3B15%3B%3B%3BFalse&DialogTitle=Select%20People%20and%20Groups&DialogImage=%2F_layouts%2F15%2Fimages%2Fppeople.gif&PickerDialogType=Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeoplePickerDialog%2C%20Microsoft.SharePoint%2C%20Version%3D15.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D71e9bce111e9429c&ForceClaims=False&DisableClaims=False&EnabledClaimProviders=&EntitySeparator=%3B%EF%BC%9B??????&DefaultSearch=&IsDlg=1%20HTTP/1.1)). Execution Time=33.8457   b64fc99f-a77d-606a-5b6e-9277e66637ec
05/19/2021 12:07:26.08  w3wp.exe (0x56FC)                           0x5788  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              aitsz   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 05/19/2021 12:07:25.89, Original Level: Verbose] The Request Management Service is offline or unprovisioned. Request Management is disabled. Status = {0}  b64fc99f-b77b-606a-5b6e-94801d8e61cd
05/19/2021 12:07:26.08  w3wp.exe (0x56FC)                           0x5788  SharePoint Foundation           Asp Runtime                     aj1kn   High        [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] SPRequestModule.AcquireRequestStateHandler b64fc99f-b77b-606a-5b6e-94801d8e61cd
05/19/2021 12:07:26.08  w3wp.exe (0x56FC)                           0x5788  SharePoint Foundation           General                         fbv5    Medium      SoapAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetUpdatedFormDigestInformation    b64fc99f-b77b-606a-5b6e-94801d8e61cd
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update searchforests for the Central Admin Site (WebApp)

```
stsadm –o setproperty –pn peoplepicker-searchadforests –pv <list of forests or domains> -url <WebApp>
```

For more info visit [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-2007-products-and-technologies/cc263460(v=office.12))
and [also this](https://documentation.help/Stsadm/f3988343-c57a-4f92-b523-682b7a5e9aa8.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Unfortunately,  it still not working.

I'm wondering why in my WebApp(Site collection) is working fine without configuring searchforest.

Comment: -this is my Central admin host:(not working)
http://vgr1:5834


-this is my web application(Site collections)(working fine)
http://vgr1:80

Comment: I still believe the central admin has not been set up correctly. You can check the property for the other WebApp and see how it was set up. Here is [another link](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2014/01/powershell-for-people-picker-properties/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to copy the web config of my WebApp and applied it in my central admin. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

First check **AD features** are are installed or not.

Or

Then using stsadm this command execute.

```
STSADM.exe -o getsiteuseraccountdirectorypath -url http://intranet
```

If you get output like this:

```
DC=childdomain,DC=rootdomain,DC=local
```

Then you need to run the following command to change the people picker search scope to search the entire forest:

```
STSADM.exe -o setsiteuseraccountdirectorypath -path "" -url http://intranet
```

OR

Using this powershell script:

```
$webapp = get-spwebapplication http://myurl.com
$webapp.peoplepickersettings
#this showed that there was something set in a sub property of peoplepickersettings called ActiveDirectoryCustomFilter.
#next step to fix this was to reset that property, the code below was used:
$webapp = get-spwebapplication http://myurl.com
$webapp.peoplepickersettings.ActiveDirectoryCustomFilter = $null
$webapp.update()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to copy the web config of my WebApp and applied in my central admin. Now it is working.